# How to change language of Map Intent?

Tags: android, dictionary, android-intent

I am trying to open a map using an intent and for that I am using

```
btn_open_map.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=24.4620769,54.5920432&hl=zh");
        try {
            Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
            startActivity(mapIntent);
        }
        catch (ActivityNotFoundException exception) {
        }
    }
});
```

but right now the default language for the map is english but I have have passed zh for chinese. If the same url when I use with browser it is working fine. On passing zh it is showing chinese map content and ru for russian. For example [Chinese](http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=24.4620769,54.5920432&hl=zh)
[Russian](http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=24.4620769,54.5920432&hl=zh)

But not in android. Anybody can suggest me how can I open it in android. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried below way to open google map :-

```
// if your query having spaces
Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("geo:37.7749,-122.4194?hl=" + Uri.encode("zh")); 
or 
Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("geo:37.7749,-122.4194?hl=zh");

Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
if (mapIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
    startActivity(mapIntent);
}
```

for info you can read from below link:-
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#Maps

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/android-intents

Comment: Google map language still not changed. You can see the changes in above link russian and chinese. All the content is changing into either russing or chinese on selecting the given language

Comment: http://technology.ezeenow.com/posts/9987/How_to_change_language_in_android_google_maps_v2_programmatically